# Show custom field in query list in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.2

I want to create a dropdown with custom field but my list query append id field into the query. How to show only selected fields in my query.

```
$this->loadModel('CardTypes');
$cardTypes = $this->CardTypes->find('list')->select(['code', 'name']);
```

In my view

```
$this->Form->select('card_type_id', $cardTypes, [ 'default' => 'DELTA']);
```

Comment: `$this->CardTypes->find('list', ['keyField' => 'code', 'valueField' => 'name'])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see the [**manual**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#finding-key-value-pairs)

```
$cardTypes = $this->CardTypes->->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'code',
    'valueField' => 'name'
]);
```