# How to Create Custom Field Types w/ CakePHP 3.0

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

Is there a way you can create custom field types with CakePHP 3.0? Do you do it via PHPMyAdmin or a Bake Plugin. I want to do it for custom fields for this custom portal I been working on that is built off of Cake's Bookmarker tutorial? Any direction on the next steps I should do to move forward?

Comment: Next step, database docs... **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-types**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831063/show-custom-field-in-query-list-in-cakephp3